# Best way to have amplify (cognito) permissions depending on groups on a trello like app

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I’m currently testing amplify.
I created some todo apps, set up cognito, all working fine.

Now I’m trying to replicate a trello board system, with users and permissions, and I have no idea how to accomplish that with cognito, and wether the best way would be (i guess cognito groups), so, what I have in mind is:

- A board will create a cognito user group.
- The user creating the board will be assigned to the new group.
- Each user invited to the board will be assigned to that group.
- Each user will have only access to the boards (groups) they are in and all the cards in those groups.

Am i missing something? Anyone can please provide any guidance?

Thanks